# How to use verification email with multi auth in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email-verification

I set up a multi auth Laravel system with two guards: "user" and "customer".
Now I would like to verify the mail of new registered customers (but not of the users).

I've added

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

and

```
class Customer extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

to Custom model.

I've added

```
Route::get('email/resend', 'CustomerAuth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
Route::get('email/verify', 'CustomerAuth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'CustomerAuth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
```

to Routes

I've builded "verify.blade" in views/auth

I've created CustomerAuth\VerificationController

**Now Laravel sends a verification email to new customer, but it doesn't verify it nor show any message.** If the customer clicks on the verification link Laravel sends back the customer to home.

Here app/Http/Controllers/CustomerAuth/VerificationController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\CustomerAuth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
class VerificationController extends Controller
{    
use VerifiesEmails;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
    $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
}
}
```

I've tried also
     `$this->middleware('auth:customer');`

auth.php

```
return [
'defaults' => [
'guard' => 'user',
'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
'user' => [
'driver' => 'session',
'provider' => 'users',
],
'customer' => [
'driver' => 'session',
'provider' => 'customers',
],
'web' => [
'driver' => 'session',
'provider' => 'users',
],
'api' => [
'driver' => 'token',
'provider' => 'users',
'hash' => false,
],
],
'providers' => [
'users' => [
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model' => App\User::class,
],
'customers' => [
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model' => App\Customer::class,
],
],
'passwords' => [
'customers' => [
'provider' => 'customers',
'table' => 'customer_password_resets',
'expire' => 60,
],
'users' => [
'provider' => 'users',
'table' => 'user_password_resets',
'expire' => 60,
],  
],
];
```

Comment: I see, i thought it would work with ```$this->middleware('auth:customer');```, how did you set up the guard?

Comment: Thank you. This is auth.php

Comment: I put in the question now, so you can read it well.